# Converting a column in Dataframe to string resulting in incomplete data, Increase the length of string

Tags: python, dataframe

Data in column 'A' of Dataframe

```
'45-54 on Treatment for less than 1 month (Patient) '
'Ocetech| 65-74 Male  on Treatment for 10 years or more (Patient) '
'What is this?  Don&#39;t know screen name | 65-74 Female  on Treatment for 6 months to less than 1 year (Patient) '
```

Converting column 'A' to string

```
c2 = c1.to_string(columns = ['A'])
```

After converting and storing it to c2 the text in the rows is not complete, half of the text is not showing.

**Current Output:**

```
'45-54 on Treatment for less than 1 ...
'Ocetech| 65-74 Male  on Treatment f...
'What is this?  Don&#39;t know scree...
```

I tried to increase the string length by using

```
c2 = c1['A'].astype('|S80')
```

But it shows error,

```
SystemError: <class 'UnicodeEncodeError'> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this:

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 1000
```

But if that does not work, try ensuring that all of your strings are utf-8 when you load them.

Comment: I changed my encoding to "ISO-8859-1" and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out!